# Telerik OpenAccess : Mapping for class is specified in file 'config' but the class could not be found

Tags: c#, service, telerik, telerik-open-access, openaccess

I have a windows service, in C#, that is using Telerik Open Access.  When I call the following code (query), I get the error below.
**Code**

```
                    var updateRecords =
                        _context.Contracts.First(
                            s => s.ContractId == model.ContractId);
```

**Error**

> Mapping for class 'Store.Data.User' is specified in file 'config' but the class could not be found. --> StoreModel/namespace[Store.Data]/class[User]

I suspect the error is not related to the query itself, but with the repository/OpenAccess configuration.

Does anyone have an insight into this?

Thanks!

Comment: The error appears when User is available in the mapping configuration of your data access layer, but in fact its code is missing from the compiled assembly. Do you use the Classic mapping approach of OpenAccess ORM or the contemporary? If you are using the contemporary approach, do you have an .rlinq file or a fluent model? If you are using an .rlinq file, does the error re-appear after you open it in [Visual Designer](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/feature-reference/tools/visual-designer/developemnt-environment-wizards-dialogs-model-tools-designer-designer) and save it (Ctrl + S)?

Comment: Thanks Doroteya!  I think you pointed us in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing the Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime reference